# BPF verifier rejects with "Permission denied (13)!" when using bpf_trace_printk()

Tags: c, ebpf, bpf

I'm trying to load an example BPF filter but I'm getting the following error:

```
Prog section 'classifier' rejected: Permission denied (13)!
 - Type:         3
 - Instructions: 58 (0 over limit)
 - License:      GPL

Verifier analysis:

0: (bf) r6 = r1
1: (61) r2 = *(u32 *)(r6 +80)
2: (61) r1 = *(u32 *)(r6 +76)
3: (bf) r3 = r1
4: (07) r3 += 14
5: (2d) if r3 > r2 goto pc+50
 R1_w=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=14,imm=0) R2_w=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R3_w=pkt(id=0,off=14,r=14,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
6: (bf) r3 = r1
7: (07) r3 += 15
8: (2d) if r3 > r2 goto pc+47
 R1_w=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=15,imm=0) R2_w=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R3_w=pkt(id=0,off=15,r=15,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
9: (71) r3 = *(u8 *)(r1 +13)
10: (67) r3 <<= 8
11: (71) r4 = *(u8 *)(r1 +12)
12: (4f) r3 |= r4
13: (57) r3 &= 65535
14: (55) if r3 != 0x8 goto pc+41
 R1=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=15,imm=0) R2=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R3=inv8 R4=inv(id=0,umax_value=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff)) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
15: (71) r3 = *(u8 *)(r1 +23)
invalid access to packet, off=23 size=1, R1(id=0,off=23,r=15)
R1 offset is outside of the packet
processed 16 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 1 peak_states 1 mark_read 1

Error fetching program/map!
Unable to load program
```

I'm using the following commands to compile and load:

```
# clang -O2 -Wall -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -target bpf -c classifier.c -o classifier.o
# tc filter add dev wlp0s20f3 ingress bpf obj classifier.o flowid 0:
```

If I comment out the line ***trace_printk("Yes! It is HTTP!\n");*** it loads. trace_printk() is a macro, I've also tried to call bpf_trace_printk() directly but with the same result.

```
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/in.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/pkt_cls.h>
//#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

#define SEC(NAME) __attribute__((section(NAME), used))

#if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
#define __bpf_htons(x) __builtin_bswap16(x)
#define __bpf_constant_htons(x) ___constant_swab16(x)
#elif __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__
#define __bpf_htons(x) (x)
#define __bpf_constant_htons(x) (x)
#else
#error "Fix your compiler's __BYTE_ORDER__?!"
#endif

#define bpf_htons(x) \
  (__builtin_constant_p(x) ? __bpf_constant_htons(x) : __bpf_htons(x))

static long (*bpf_trace_printk)(const char *fmt, __u32 fmt_size,
                               ...) = (void *)BPF_FUNC_trace_printk;

#define trace_printk(fmt, ...)                                       \
    do {                                                         \
        char _fmt[] = fmt;                                   \
        bpf_trace_printk(_fmt, sizeof(_fmt), ##__VA_ARGS__); \
    } while (0)

static inline int is_http(struct __sk_buff *skb, __u64 nh_off);
unsigned long long load_byte(void *skb,
                             unsigned long long off) asm("llvm.bpf.load.byte");

SEC("classifier")
static inline int classification(struct __sk_buff *skb) {
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)skb->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)skb->data;
    struct ethhdr *eth = data;

    __u16 h_proto;
    __u64 nh_off = 0;
    nh_off = sizeof(*eth);

    if (data + nh_off > data_end) {
        return TC_ACT_OK;
    }

    h_proto = eth->h_proto;

    if (h_proto == bpf_htons(ETH_P_IP)) {
        if (is_http(skb, nh_off) == 1) {
            trace_printk("Yes! It is HTTP!\n"); // (ERROR)
        }
    }

    return TC_ACT_OK;
}

static inline int is_http(struct __sk_buff *skb, __u64 nh_off) {
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)skb->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)skb->data;
    struct iphdr *iph = data + nh_off;

    if ((void*)iph + 1 > data_end) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (iph->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP) {
        return 0;
    }
    __u32 tcp_hlen = 0;
    __u32 ip_hlen = 0;
    __u32 poffset = 0;
    __u32 plength = 0;
    __u32 ip_total_length = iph->tot_len;

    ip_hlen = iph->ihl << 2;

    if (ip_hlen < sizeof(*iph)) {
        return 0;
    }

    struct tcphdr *tcph = data + nh_off + sizeof(*iph);

    if ((void*)tcph + 1 > data_end) {
        return 0;
    }

    tcp_hlen = tcph->doff << 2;

    poffset = ETH_HLEN + ip_hlen + tcp_hlen;
    plength = ip_total_length - ip_hlen - tcp_hlen;
    if (plength >= 7) {
        unsigned long p[7];
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

            p[i] = load_byte(skb, poffset + i);
        }
        if ((p[0] == 'H') && (p[1] == 'T') && (p[2] == 'T') && (p[3] == 'P')) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is the `trace_printk` itself. It's probably just that when you comment that line, the compiler optimizes out a lot of code (e.g., `is_http()` isn't needed anymore) and the error disappears.

Comment: You're right @pchaigno, the problem is indeed inside is_http()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trace_printk` isn't actually the issue here. It just seems that way because once you comment that statement, the verifier optimizes out the call to `is_http()`; it's not needed anymore.

**What's going on?**

The verifier is rejecting your BPF program with the following error:

```
invalid access to packet, off=23 size=1, R1(id=0,off=23,r=15)
R1 offset is outside of the packet
```

That means you are trying to access the packet at offset 23 even though you only verified that it is 15 bytes long.

**Where the bug?**

I suspect the bug is in those lines:

```
if ((void*)iph + 1 > data_end) {
    return 0;
}
```

Here, you are checking that `data_end` is larger or equal to `iph` plus one byte. We can see it in the verifier output:

```
3: (bf) r3 = r1
4: (07) r3 += 14
5: (2d) if r3 > r2 goto pc+50
 R1_w=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=14,imm=0) R2_w=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R3_w=pkt(id=0,off=14,r=14,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
6: (bf) r3 = r1
7: (07) r3 += 15
8: (2d) if r3 > r2 goto pc+47
 R1_w=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=15,imm=0) R2_w=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R3_w=pkt(id=0,off=15,r=15,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
```

The first comparison is for `data + nh_off > data_end`, the second is for `(void*)iph + 1 > data_end`. As you can see there's only one byte in difference.

**What's the fix?**

I think you want:

```
if ((void*)(iph + 1) > data_end) {
    return 0;
}
```

And the same for the next packet bounds check (tcp).

Comment: It worked!!! I also changed from "if ((void*)(iph + 1) > data_end)" to "if ((void*)iph + sizeof(struct iphdr) > data_end)" just to make it more readable.